2SLS: does it just rescale the instrument variable?
I am investigating using instrument variables to correct for some known sources of measurement error in my data (measures that reflect mistakes/inconsistencies that we think directly affect our main measures of interest).
I have tried doing 2SLS by hand and using Linnearmodels IV2SLS.
However, when I look at the X_hat variable, and plot it against the instrument variable. All that has happened is a rescaling of the instrument:
X1 = my independent variable of interest
DSC_2 = the instrument variable (measure of the source of measurement error)
res_first = IV2SLS(data["X1"], data[["const", "DSC_2"]], None, None).fit(
    cov_type="unadjusted"
)
print(res_first)
data["X_hat"] = data.X1 - res_first.resids 


The results are the same regardless of whether I use 2SLS by hand or IV2SLS.
I don't really understand how this improves our model (but I would like to understand!).
Am I incorrectly specifying 2SLS? Or is this rescaling the effect? How does this change things? Is the 'tuning' effect of 2SLS just a rescaling to a more appropriate place?
*more about my data can be seen here What statistical method for assessing the effect of a known measurement error variable? . 2SLS is following on from a suggestion in this post concerning structural equation modelling.
